# Python Tkinter TextEditor how to save configuration changes

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm very new to Tkinter but i tried to read all the documentation that i could and could not understand if i'm heading in the right direction or not.
Firstly, thank you for reading this.
In summary i'm trying to create a Text Editor with Tkinter. This text editor however must display the exact same file for every user which opens it in the same private network as it is to be used as a display Panel in order for everyone to be able to read anyone else's notices.
I Have still a lot to do but where i'm blocking right now and couldn't find an answer for is to be able to store the configurations changes that are applied to the text (Bold, color etc..)
the text itself is stored in a txt file that is automatically opened at the start of the program but i don't know a way to store the color and font style.
To apply the font and color to the text i use a counter that i apply to each tag change that is done (so the first area selection that will be changed will be named "colortag1" the second "colortag2" etc ..)
I don't know if it is possible to keep theses tags configurations and the count of my variable "counter" stored without reseting everything.
Would someone possibly have an idea?
I'm really sorry if it's not very understandable.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *


class Notepad:
   #Creation of a Notepad Class
    __root = Tk()
    __countG = 1
    __thisWidth = 300
    __thisHeight = 300
    __thisTextArea = Text(__root)
    __thisMenuBar = Menu(__root)
    __thisFileMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)
    __thisEditMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)

    __thisScrollBar = Scrollbar(__thisTextArea)

    #The file that is always opened by the notepad
    __file = "//srvad/echange/Python panel/paneltest.txt"
    __thisTextArea.configure(font=("arial", "12" ,"normal"))
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.__root.wm_iconbitmap("Notepad.ico")
        except:
            pass

        try:
            self.__thisWidth = kwargs['width']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        try:
            self.__thisHeight = kwargs['height']
        except KeyError:
            pass



        #Creation of Edit Cascade
        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Edit",
                                            menu=self.__thisEditMenu)

        #Name of the text editor
        self.__root.title("Home Panel")

        #Size and settings of the Notepad
        screenWidth = self.__root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenHeight = self.__root.winfo_screenheight()

        left = (screenWidth / 2) - (self.__thisWidth / 2)

        top = (screenHeight / 2) - (self.__thisHeight / 2)

        self.__root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.__thisWidth,
                                              self.__thisHeight,
                                              left, top))

        self.__root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.__root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.__thisTextArea.grid(sticky=N + E + S + W)

        #Call of the Bold function
        self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Gras",font=("arial", "12", "bold"),
                                       command=self.__gras)



        self.__root.config(menu=self.__thisMenuBar)

        self.__thisScrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.__thisScrollBar.config(command=self.__thisTextArea.yview)
        self.__thisTextArea.config(yscrollcommand=self.__thisScrollBar.set)


        file = open(self.__file, "r")

        self.__thisTextArea.insert(1.0, file.read())

        file.close()

    #Bold function (the counter permit to generate a new tag name each time the function is called.
   # The function check the counter number in order to decide if the text selection is in bold or normal font
   # So the counter get +1 in one case an +2 in the other to differentiate them
    def __gras(self):
        sele=self.__thisTextArea.get(SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
        print (sele)
        if self.__thisTextArea.tag_ranges('sel'):
            if "colortag" + str(self.__countG -1) in self.__thisTextArea.tag_names(SEL_FIRST):
                self.__thisTextArea.tag_add('colortag' + str(self.__countG), SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)
                print ("le texte est gras")

                self.__thisTextArea.tag_configure('colortag' + str(self.__countG),font=("arial", "12", "normal"))
                self.__countG +=2

            else:
                self.__thisTextArea.tag_add('colortag' + str(self.__countG), SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)
                print ('le texte est en normal')
                self.__thisTextArea.tag_configure('colortag' + str(self.__countG), font=("arial", "12", "bold"))
                self.__countG += 1

        else:
            pass


    def __quitApplication(self):
        self.__root.destroy()

#Save function that save the actual text in a .txt file
    def __saveFile(self):

        if self.__file == None:

            self.__file = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt',
                                            defaultextension=".txt",
                                            filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                                                       ("Text Documents", "*.txt")])

            if self.__file == "":
                self.__file = None
            else:

                file = open(self.__file, "w")
                file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END))
                file.close()

                self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad")


        else:
            file = open(self.__file, "w")
            file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END))
            file.close()


    def run(self):

        self.__root.mainloop()


notepad = Notepad(width=600, height=400)
notepad.run()
```

'''

Comment: Please try to reduce the code to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code that isn't directly related to the question being asked. Since you're asking about saving and restoring text attributes, you can probably illustrate that with a couple dozen lines of code instead of a couple hundred.

Comment: Hello, yes you're right, i'm very sorry. Is this better or still way too long ? i will try to do a really reduced one this afternoon but i'm still so much of a newbie that it's not so easy ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look into Pythons pickle functionality, there is no way to do what you want without saving the tags in a separate file or writing the tags into the file itself.

Comment: Ok thank you , i have tried to look in on pickle and the dump() functionality but it seemed fairly difficult to convert back the tags into configurations, especially when it will need to load a lot of theses tags. I'll try getting back into some more doc later. I thank you for your answer